# DTProbLog query

Tags: prolog, probabilistic-programming

i'm using DTProblog in ProbLog version 2.1.0.34 downloaded
from the bitbucket repository at https://bitbucket.org/problog/problog/src/develop/.
To run a program which uses dtproblog i type on terminal

> $ problog dt program.pl

Looking at the examples in the bitbucket repository at
https://bitbucket.org/problog/problog/src/develop/test/dtproblog/viralmarketing.pl
i see that several queries are allowed, such as `dtproblog_ev/2` ecc...
How can i run one of those queries from the command line?

I've tried also to open a shell using

> $ problog shell

but when i try to load a program using `consult/1` (https://problog.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cli.html#interactive-shell-shell)
i have an error:

> ?- consult('viralmarketing.pl').
>
> Traceback....
>
> TypeError: _builtin_consult() takes at least 2 arguments (3 given)

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've posted the same question in the ProbLog mailing list. I've received an answer: basically, queries as `dtproblog_ev/2` are no more supported in the newest version of ProbLog. 
Regarding the `consult/1` issue, it was a bug and now is fixed.